# How to use claim based authorization to hide /show UI controls using identity 2.1 in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, claims-based-identity

Right now I am using list of claims in my UI, below code is being used to achieve this task. Getting the claim list of current logged in user and passing list in view and manipulating list to show/hide controls on UI.

```
List<string> lstClaimVM = new List<string>();
var lstClaims = this.User.Claims;

if (lstClaims != null)
{
    ClaimVM objClaimVM = new ClaimVM();
    foreach (var claim in lstClaims)
    {
        lstClaimVM.Add(claim.Value);
    }
    objAssetGridDataVM.lstClaimVM = lstClaimVM;
}
else
{
    objAssetGridDataVM.lstClaimVM = lstClaimVM = new List<string>();
}
```

And below code is being used to show/hide UI controls in screen. I also have policies and using on controller and action which is working fine for me, but when it comes to the UI need something which can be used to play with the UI controls. If user have "view"claim than cannot perform any operation just view the item.

```
if (claimList !== null) {
    var viewClaim = false;
    for (var i = 0; i <= claimList.length; i++) {
        if (claimList[i] === 'Assets View') {
            viewClaim = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Here I am checking the particular claim type if user have view only permission than hiding the buttons and making entire screen read only.

```
if (viewClaim) {
    for (var j = 0; j <= claimList.length; j++) {
        if (claimList[j] === 'Assets Edit') {
            viewClaim = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (viewClaim) {
    $('#btnAddNewAsset').hide();
    // $('#EditAssets').text('View');
}
else {
    $('#btnAddNewAsset').show();
}
```

I don't know weather it is a good approach or not if someone have any idea please shade some light on it.